# What does it mean for a Chern class to be an invariant

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

How would you explain to someone who barely knows math why a Chern class is an invariant and also what K-theory is and what it is for? im a theorist and i have taken very few math classes in my undergrad, i am trying to study more math every time but this is very hard for me and i need it to understand for a quantization of gravity and i would like someone to explain it to me the least formal and intuitive way possible please.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start with a disclaimer that a lot of the below is simplified and handwavy, but it felt like the best option for OP.

$K$-theory measures something called vector bundles on a space.

If you have a space $X$, you can assign to every point a (complex) vector space of dimension $n$ (that is, a space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$), where $n$ is fixed. However, we would want to do this in a way that is somehow consistent and not just random. A way of doing this is taking a map $E \xrightarrow{p} X$ such that the fiber (that is, the preimage) of every point in $X$ is $\mathbb{C}^n$.

So that our space $E$ does not look particularly complicated, we ask that this is locally trivial. This means that for any point $x \in X$, there is an open neighbourhood such that $p^{-1} (U) \cong U \times \mathbb{C}^n$, since the product is the easiest way of assigning to every point a complex vector space of dimension $n$. Of course, this isomorphism can't just be anything. It needs to be consistent with the existing structure. This means there is a commutative diagram

$$\begin{array}{cc} & U \times \mathbb{C}^n& \\ ~~~\cong\nearrow && \searrow ~~~~\\ p^{-1} (U) & \underset{\large p}{\longrightarrow} & \overset{\phantom{-}}{U} \end{array}$$

where the map $U \times \mathbb{C}^n \to U$ is the obvious projection.

A map $E \to X$ that is locally trivial as above is called a vector bundle of dimension $n$.

A natural question mathematicians like to ask is what do *all* vector bundles over a space look like (there is a notion of isomorphism of vector bundles). Let $S$ be this set. Note that there is a notion of addition on $S$. For two vector bundles, $E \to X$ and $E' \to X$ of dimension $n$ and $n'$, we have a vector bundle $E \oplus E' \to X$ that is of dimension $n + n'$ (this is called the Whitney sum, and the space $E \oplus E'$ is a subspace of $E \times E'$). The main idea you should take from the Whitney sum is that the fiber at every point is the sum of the fibers at each of the other bundles.

We can now take the Grothendieck completion of this monoid. This consists of just formally adjoining inverses to every element. For example, the Grothendieck completion of the monoid $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ since we have adjoined inverses for every element. This gives us an abelian group $K^0 (X)$.

It turns out that this group has even more structure. It is also possible to take a tensor product of vector bundles, which I won't go into much detail, but it is very much like the whitney sum in that it just takes the tensor product fiberwise. This tensor product gives $K^0 (X)$ the structure of a commutative ring. That is, we have addition (whitney sum) and multiplication (tensor product).

There are higher $K$-groups that turn this into a cohomology theory, but I am not sure you need that!

Instead of all vector bundles, one can just consider line bundles on a space $X$. That is, vector bundles of dimension $1$. There is a map from the set of all line bundles in a space X to the second cohomology group of $X$, $H^2 (X)$. This turns out to be a bijection, so to understand all line bundles on a space $X$, it is enough to compute its singular cohomology. For a line bundle $L \to X$, we call the associated element $c_1 (L) \in H^2 (X)$ its (first) Chern class.

The abelian group structure also carries through. Line bundles form a monoid with the tensor product (since the tensor product of two lines is a line). This works well with Chern classes because
$$ c_1 (L \otimes L') = c_1 (L) + c_1 (L')$$
It is possible to define analogues for higher dimensional bundles as well (although these usually don't classify all the bundles like in the $1$-dimensional case).

This is an invariant because isomorphic line bundles give the same Chern class.

Comment: Thanks  really thanks